# How to assign values based on string groupings in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, list, grouping

I have accounting data in SQL. These are entries made for a sale so for every sale made there is an offsetting entry for cost of goods. When a customer buys the same product but in different quantities it will have the same memo line just a different amount for the sales and cost of goods sold. In the accounting system we use, it auto generates a transaction id in the TxnId column only for the sales lines not for the cost of goods sold lines for some reason unknown to me. I extract the data using the following query:

```
SELECT
    account,
    name, 
    memo, 
    debit,
    credit,
    amount,
    txnid,
    refnum,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY memo, refnumber ORDER BY account,memo,abs(amount)) AS memo_group 
FROM [dbo].[Table] 
WHERE refnumber = '67175'
```

The resulting table looks like this:

```
  Account                Name       Memo           Debit    Credit   Amount   TxnID      RefNum    Row_Counter 
Sales                Company A    Wingding 1     Null     855       855    5EASUC-X    12345        1
Sales                Company A    Wingding 1     Null     400       400    5EASUC-X    12345        2
CostofGoodsSold      Company A    Wingding 1     -650     Null     -650    Null        12345        3
CostofGoodsSold      Company A    Wingding 1     -200     Null     -200    Null        12345        4
Sales                Company A    Wingding 2     Null     760       760    5EASUC-X    12345        1
Sales                Company A    Wingding 2     Null     665       665    5EASUC-X    12345        2
CostofGoodsSold      Company A    Wingding 2     -600     Null     -600    Null        12345        3
CostofGoodsSold      Company A    Wingding 2     -465     Null     -465    Null        12345        4
```

What I am trying to do is assign the credit amount in the sales rows to the corresponding cost of goods sold rows in another column while keeping the same amount for the sales line. I'm hoping to get a table that looks like this:

```
    Account                Name       Memo           Debit    Credit   Amount   TxnID      RefNum    Row_Counter   New_Col
    Sales                Company A    Wingding 1     Null     855       855    5EASUC-X    12345        1         855
    Sales                Company A    Wingding 1     Null     400       400    5EASUC-X    12345        2         400
    CostofGoodsSold      Company A    Wingding 1     -650     Null     -650    Null        12345        3         855
    CostofGoodsSold      Company A    Wingding 1     -200     Null     -200    Null        12345        4         400
    Sales                Company A    Wingding 2     Null     760       760    5EASUC-X    12345        1         760
    Sales                Company A    Wingding 2     Null     665       665    5EASUC-X    12345        2         665
    CostofGoodsSold      Company A    Wingding 2     -600     Null     -600    Null        12345        3         760
    CostofGoodsSold      Company A    Wingding 2     -465     Null     -465    Null        12345        4         665
```

I've tried using windows functions to do this but without any luck. Does anybody have any suggestions on a way to do this?

Comment: can you explain the logic of credit assignment with reference to the sample data that you shown ?

Comment: How do you (you - the person) know that the 855 sale amount goes with 650 cost amount? The short answer is you probably can't do this is a reliable, repeatable manner. Your partitioning in the row_numer includes amount - but there is no direct relationship between sales amount and cost amount. You made an assumption here. Is that a "good" assumption? What happens when there are multiple sales of the same item in the same "transaction"? Accounting data can get very complicated and very weird.

Comment: And i'll point out that the words "debit" and "credit" imply addition or subtraction based on the type of account. Tread carefully here since your actual numbers are saved as negative values. Want to see complicated? Examine a corrected transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a combination of CTEs and Window Functions. Once ordered the way you have them in your CTE you can make the new column use the LAG function which copies the data from the prior row "until it sees a new product". This also assumes that you have a PrimaryKey like ProductNo that will marry the two. I hope this helps.